# Entering a 2 word answer causes batch file to crash. How can I avoid this?

Tags: batch-file, crash

I am just writing a silly little program, but the problem I'm having seems quite generic.

Here is the part of the code that is causing me problems:

Warning: the code opens a google search.

```
set /a c=0
:Longcat
CLS
Echo.
ECHO *****************************************************************
ECHO.
echo            How LONG is this cat?
echo.
echo *****************************************************************
Echo.
timeout 5 >nul
If %c%==0 start https://www.google.com/search?q=LongCat
set /a c=%c%+1
If %c%==10 goto incorrect
Set /p cat=
If %cat%==long goto correct
goto Longcat
:correct
Echo correct
pause
Goto geometric
:incorrect
echo incorrect
pause
goto geometric
```

When I enter single word responses for `/p cat=`, like `big` or `tall`, the program works fine (continues to `GOTO LONGCAT`).

But as soon as I use a 2 word answer, like `very big`, I get an error:

> big==long was unexpected at this time.

Does anyone have an explanation or a fix for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Does anyone have an explanation or a fix for this?

```
If %cat%==long goto correct
```

If you enter `very big` then the above command expands to:

```
If very big==long goto correct
```

which is a syntax error:

> big==long was unexpected at this time.

You need to add quotes (`"`s) to your `if` comparison to compare multi word inputs:

```
If "%cat%"=="long" goto correct
```

Now, if you enter `very big` then the above command expands to:

```
If "very big"=="long" goto correct
```

which is a valid command.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) - Conditionally perform a command.